# Проблема с отправкой сообщения на сервер json данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

При помощи библиотеки **requests** на **python 3.8.3** отправляю следующие данные:

```
data = "{"extendedData": {"measureType": "млн. руб."}}"
    
response = requests.post(
url = url,
json = json.loads(data)
)
```

На выходе получаю **Response[200]**

Но на сервере получаю следующие данные :
`"{"extendedData": {"measureType": "\u043c\u043b\u043d. \u0440\u0443\u0431."}}"`

Как получить данные на русском языке? как только не менял кодировки - не получается получить требуемый результат.

**UPD.**
решилось, как стал отправлять следующим образом:

```
 response = requests.post(
    url = url,
    data = json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
    )
```

Спасибо всем

Comment: кодировку терпинала, оси откуда отправляете проверяли? https://qna.habr.com/q/702078

Comment: Да, конечно. ещё если отправляю информацию ту же самую или через curl или через Postman, то всё нормально и русский язык по-человечески выглядит

Comment: json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412714/using-json-dumps-with-ensure-ascii-true

Comment: нет, я создаю объект через json.loads(data) после чего отправляю его POST отправкой

json.dumps() не подходит (

Answer (score 1):

Вполне может помочь задать саму кодировку сценария

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

И провести явное преобразование

```
json.dumps(myvar, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8').decode()
```